# É possível consumir dados de um webservice dentro de um SQLServer diretamente?

Tags: sql-server, web-service

Tenho que fazer a migração de uma base de dados em MySQL para outra em SQLServer. Nessa migração, tenho o seguinte problema: nem todos os cadastros de endereço estão completos mas eu tenho o CEP da maioria deles. Minha idéia então é:

- Utilizar o serviço do site http://viacep.com.br para completar meus dados.

Já pensei em inúmeras formas de fazer isso, creio que a melhor maneira seja através de um cursor mas, não sei como capturar esses dados diretamente de dentro do SQLServer. É possível consumir esses dados **diretamente** sem a necessidade de criar uma pequena API ou algo do tipo?

Comment: já achei uma forma de fazer isso na verdade já até criei minha função que faça isso rsrs

Comment: Sim, eu [percebi depois que isso já era possível no próprio SQL-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332298/connect-to-a-webservice-from-sql). Nem imaginava, rsrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oamethod-transact-sql). O SQLServer (o meu na versão 2016) têm o recurso para consumir dados de um webservice e baseado nele fazer a captura dos dados. O Resultado final da minha função ficou desse jeito:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'dbo.fnViaCep') AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fnViaCep];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnViaCep(@CEP varchar(10)) 
RETURNS @T TABLE (
    cep varchar(10),
    logradouro varchar(100),
    complemento varchar(100),
    bairro varchar(100),
    localidade varchar(100),
    unidade varchar(100),
    uf char(2),
    ibge char(7),
    gia varchar(10)
) AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @authHeader VARCHAR(64),
            @contentType VARCHAR(64),
            @postData VARCHAR(2000),
            @responseText VARCHAR(2000),
            @responseXML VARCHAR(2000),
            @ret INT,
            @status VARCHAR(32),
            @statusText VARCHAR(32),
            @token INT,
            @url VARCHAR(256),
            @xml XML;

    SET @authHeader = 'BASIC 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
    SET @contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    SET @url = 'http://viacep.com.br/ws/' + @CEP + '/xml/';

    -- Open the connection.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    -- IF @ret <> 0 PRINT (CAST('Unable to open HTTP connection.' AS INT));

    -- Send the request.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL

    -- Handle the response.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

    SET @xml = CONVERT(XML, replace(@responseText,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',''), 1);

    INSERT INTO @T
    SELECT
        t.c.value('cep[1]', 'varchar(10)') as cep,  
        t.c.value('logradouro[1]', 'varchar(100)') as logradouro,  
        t.c.value('complemento[1]', 'varchar(100)') as complemento,
        t.c.value('bairro[1]', 'varchar(100)') as bairro,
        t.c.value('localidade[1]', 'varchar(100)') as localidade,
        t.c.value('unidade[1]', 'varchar(100)') as unidade,
        t.c.value('uf[1]', 'char(2)') as uf,
        t.c.value('ibge[1]', 'char(7)') as ibge
        t.c.value('gia[1]', 'varchar(10)') as gia,
    FROM @xml.nodes('//xmlcep') t(c)  

    -- Close the connection.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
    -- IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

RETURN
END
GO
```

Com isso você tem inúmeras possibilidades de validação de dados e a possibilidade de completar informações em bancos como quiser. A forma de uso é simples:

```sql
// seleção simples de um endereço usando o CEP
select * from fnViaCep('31520230')
```